# Valor $Scope de ng-model Arroja "Undefined" en el Controlador

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic

En mis estudios del Framework Ionic estoy aprendiendo sobre controladores, he estado trabajando un ejemplo sencillo de una página con un login, a continuación mi código HTML, no les dejo más porque el resto fue generado por Ionic y no lo toqué para nada

```
 <div ng-controller="controller">    
  <ion-content>
    <img class="indexImg" src="img/saludoIndex.jpg">
    <br><br>
          <div class="item item-input-inset">    
              <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <i class="icon ion-at placeholder-icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección de email" ng-model="mail">
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class="item item-input-inset">    
              <label  class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <i class="icon ion-locked placeholder-icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-model="word">
              </label><br>
          </div>

          <div class="col text-center">
              <br><h4><a>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></h4><br><br><br><br><br>
              <a class="button button-stable button-large" href="templates/Register.html">
              <b>Crear una cuenta gratuita</b></a>
          </div>


  </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive tabs">
        <a class="tab-item">
            <h4 style="color:white;" ng-click="registrar()">INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
        </a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</div>
```

Y el respectivo JavaScript

```
(function (){

var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
var app2 = angular.module('nuevo', []);

app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.registrar = function(){
    $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/php/Conexion.php",{
        correo:$scope.mail, pass:$scope.word,    
    }).success(function(data){
   console.log("exito"); 
   console.log($scope.mail);
    });
}

});

app2.controller('registroUsuario', function($scope, $http){

$scope.nuevoUsuario= function(){
    $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/php/RegistroUsuario.php",{
        tipo:$scope.tipo, cedula:$scope.cedula, nombres:$scope.nombre, apellidos:$scope.apellido, email:$scope.email, pass:$scope.contra, indicativo:$scope.indicativo, numero:$scope.numero,    
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log($scope.cedula);
        console.log($scope.nombre);
        console.log($scope.apellido);
        console.log($scope.email);
        console.log($scope.contra);
        console.log($scope.indicativo);
        console.log($scope.numero);
    });
}

});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
 })
}())
```

Específicamente hablando tengo problemas con el controlador "controller" donde con la función registrar() hago el envío de datos a un archivo PHP para hacer operaciones en la base de datos.

Antes de eso decidí probar el controlador mostrando el valor de $scope.mail pero éste me arroja "undefined" lo mismo para $scope.word, lo único que me muestra es el console.log tal cual lo llamo, eso significa que conecta exitosamente con el archivo PHP pero no me está enviando los datos que necesito para validar en la consulta (los valores $scope.mail y $scope.word.)

Lo raro es que el otro controlador configurado me funciona y hace la operación en la base de datos enviando los valores del ng-model que tiene otro formulario.

Intenté cambiando

```
app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
```

por

```
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
```

pero me arroja error. Estoy corto de ideas, a lo mejor me falta configurar algo o quitar algo, no sé, llevo poco tiempo con este framework pero me parece interesante, espero que me puedan dar una mano, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu código me doy cuenta que cuando tus datos están dentro de `<ion-content>` fallan, si sacas esa etiqueta todo va a funcionar. Ahora, esto no debería porque pasar pero te comento que quizás esa no es la manera correcta de ordenar tu proyecto.

Te recomiendo separar tu codigo (que es por defecto como lo ordena Ionic)

```
www
   templates
       login.html
       registro.html
   js
       app.js
       controllers.js
```

En el archivo `controller.js` defines todos los controladores para cada una de las vistas o templates que tengas por ejemplo :

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.registrar = function() {
        $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/php/Conexion.php", {
            correo: $scope.mail,
            pass: $scope.word,
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log("exito");
            console.log($scope.mail);
        });
    }
})

.controller('RegistroCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.nuevoUsuario = function() {
        $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/php/RegistroUsuario.php", {
            tipo: $scope.tipo,
            cedula: $scope.cedula,
            nombres: $scope.nombre,
            apellidos: $scope.apellido,
            email: $scope.email,
            pass: $scope.contra,
            indicativo: $scope.indicativo,
            numero: $scope.numero,
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log($scope.cedula);
            console.log($scope.nombre);
            console.log($scope.apellido);
            console.log($scope.email);
            console.log($scope.contra);
            console.log($scope.indicativo);
            console.log($scope.numero);
        });
    }

});
```

Despues en el archivo `app.js` inyectas la dependencia de `started.controllers` que es lo que definimos anteriormente.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'starter.controllers'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "templates/login_inicio.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
    })

    .state('registro', {
        url: '/registro',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "templates/registro.html",
        controller: "RegistroCtrl"
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Defines el nombre de la vista, la url que va a tomar, el template que ocupara y que controlador va a tener. Finalmente tu vista quedaria algo asi :

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view" cache-view="false">
    <ion-content>
    <img class="indexImg" src="img/saludoIndex.jpg">
    <br><br>
          <div class="item item-input-inset">    
              <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <i class="icon ion-at placeholder-icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección de email" ng-model="mail">
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class="item item-input-inset">    
              <label  class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <i class="icon ion-locked placeholder-icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-model="word">
              </label><br>
          </div>

          <div class="col text-center">
              <br><h4><a>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></h4><br><br><br><br><br>
              <a class="button button-stable button-large" href="templates/Register.html">
              <b>Crear una cuenta gratuita</b></a>
          </div>


  </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive tabs">
        <a class="tab-item">
            <h4 style="color:white;" ng-click="registrar()">INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
        </a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

Con esto defines que para cada vista hay un controlador, que se encarga de los valores de `$scope`. Esta mas modular tu proyecto, de facil lectura porque todo esta donde debe estar y no hay nada mezclado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, efectivamente era la etiqueta <ion-content> la quité y sirve de maravilla, además agradezco tus consejos sobre la debida estructuración del proyecto, soy nuevo en esto y de a poco salgo de dudas aprendiendo de mis errores, saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema que tienes es con el ámbito del scope. Intenta asignar los valores a un objeto antes de pasarlo y luego usa el objeto en lugar del scope.